# What is the purpose of The Four Moment Theorem for Complex Matrices?

Tags: pr.probability

How is this theorem useful in the real world? In general, what is the point of studying limiting distributions of various statistics of random matrices?

Comment: "Brevity is the soul of wit. William Shakespeare, Hamlet, Act II, scene
ii, roughly line 90 out of about 600. Spoken by Polonius. – Will Jagy", but seems in that question some additional information would be welcome.    

Comment: You can use it to build cars that go faster

Comment: "What is the point of X" is never a great question. Gradgrind, anyone?